# Updating deployment system to docker

Tags: docker, teamcity

We have a system run on 3 servers that we will need to expand in the future.

Currently, everything is done through Teamcity. We have a git branch that teamcity monitors and when we have new content in it, teamcity pulls the changes, builds the code and then update the server it runs on.
Each server has its own teamcity and each monitors part of the repository.

This system has worked well for several years without any real problems.

Now we're planning on scaling things up and we're splitting a rather monolithic system into micro-services.
We're planning on running each of these services into docker containers.

Each server's hardware is quite specialized since some services require access to a lot of storage while other services are computationally intensive.
So the distribution of services is still to be tied to some specific servers, but we need to plan for scaling.

We would like to keep the update process tied to a git branch since it has worked very well.

The first question is if it would make sense to still keep teamcity as the system to build and have it make docker container and deploy on each machine through docker compose / swarm?

Or would it be better in the long run to use other tools?

I have looked a bit at kubernetes, but what it exactly does, etc is quite vague from the docs I can find online and I'm not sure it would handle the build/deploy cycle we're looking for.

We haven't done any production with docker yet and I understand that everyone had different requirements, but it would help to hear a few success / failure stories to narrow the options to investigate.

Comment: care to explain the downvote?

Comment: From a logical standpoint, if teamcity just pulls and builds onto different docker containers, what harm can be done? If anything goes wrong there most likely are log files.

Comment: I think so as well, I'm just curious to see if anyone has had a similar pipeline and learn from their experience.

Comment: we r using teamcity with docker compose for dev and kuber for prod.